# using Variables in ansible roles

Tags: ansible

I am trying to include variables in ansible role as follows, however value is not being passed.

`{role: mysql, username: 'ansible_env.var_user', password: 'ansible_env.var_pass'}`

I have the set `var_user` and `var_pass` as environment variables.
Please let me know if any other ways to achive my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are referenced with double curly brackets:

```
{role: mysql, username: '{{ ansible_env.var_user }}', password: '{{ ansible_env.var_pass }}'}
```

See the [documentation for details](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html).